# Filter reversed rows in a dataframe (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I actually have a problem with my dataframe, indeed let's say I have a dataframe such:

```
    cluster_name    qseqid  sseqid  pident_x    qstart  qend    sstar   send
2   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    42  133 46  189
3   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    146 283 287 389
4   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    301 478 402 503
5   1   seq13_0042_0035 seq1_0035_0035  0.73    46  189 42  133
6   1   seq13_0042_0035 seq1_0035_0035  0.73    287 389 146 283
7   1   seq13_0042_0035 seq1_0035_0035  0.73    402 503 301 478
8   2   seq4_0042_0035  seq2_0035_0035  0.71    256 789 125 678
9   2   seq4_0042_0035  seq2_0035_0035  0.71    802 1056    706 985
10  2   seq4_0042_0035  seq7_0035_0042  0.83    123 745 156 723
12  4   seq11_0035_0035 seq14_0042_0035 0.89    145 647 236 921
13  4   seq11_0035_0035 seq17_0042_0042 0.97    148 623 241 1002
14  5   seq17_0035_0042 seq17_0042_0042 0.94    188 643 179 746
...
(200 000 ROWS)
```

As you can see in the lines 2,3 and 4 in the cluster 1:

```
 cluster_name    qseqid  sseqid  pident_x    qstart  qend    sstar   send
2   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    42  133 46  189
3   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    146 283 287 389
4   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    301 478 402 503
```

there are the reciprocal (reversed) ones in 5, 6 and 7 in the cluster 1:

```
 cluster_name    qseqid  sseqid  pident_x    qstart  qend    sstar   send
1   1   seq13_0042_0035 seq1_0035_0035  0.73    46  189 42  133
6   1   seq13_0042_0035 seq1_0035_0035  0.73    287 389 146 283
7   1   seq13_0042_0035 seq1_0035_0035  0.73    402 503 301 478
```

If  you do not see it well it would be like:

```
   seq 1 vs seq 2 : (here seq1_0035_0035 vs seq13_0042_0035)
```

and

```
seq 2 vs seq 1 : ( here seq13_0042_0035 vs seq1_0035_0035)
```

It is the same comparison and I do want to keep one of them only, not both.

Here for example, it's to only keep 2,3 and 4 OR 4,5 and 6 in my final dataframe, if I only keep the first ones it would give:

```
    cluster_name    qseqid  sseqid  pident_x    qstart  qend    sstar   send
2   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    42  133 46  189
3   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    146 283 287 389
4   1   seq1_0035_0035  seq13_0042_0035 0.73    301 478 402 503
8   2   seq4_0042_0035  seq2_0035_0035  0.71    256 789 125 678
9   2   seq4_0042_0035  seq2_0035_0035  0.71    802 1056    706 985
10  2   seq4_0042_0035  seq7_0035_0042  0.83    123 745 156 723
12  4   seq11_0035_0035 seq14_0042_0035 0.89    145 647 236 921
13  4   seq11_0035_0035 seq17_0042_0042 0.97    148 623 241 1002
14  5   seq17_0035_0042 seq17_0042_0042 0.94    188 643 179 746
```

as you can also see, 8 and 9 are the same sequences but they do not have the same seq coordinates (qstart, qend, sstar and send), then I keep them.

I already asked for such a thing but I actually have a dataframe with around 200 000 rows and I would like to find a solution which is not to much time consuming and also do not take to much memory because with my previous solutions it took to much time and memory...

Does someone have an idea?

Thank you very much for your help.

the first try was:

```
df[~pd.DataFrame({
    'tup': df[['sseqid', 'qseqid']].apply(tuple, axis=1), 
    'inv_tups': df[['qseqid', 'sseqid']].apply(lambda t: (tuple(t), ), axis=1).cumsum().shift(1)}
).apply(lambda r: isinstance(r.inv_tups, tuple) and r.tup in r.inv_tups, axis=1)]
```

but it takes to much time for 200 000 rows.

and the other one was:

```
this = data[["qseqid", "sseqid"]].apply(tuple, axis=1)
cum = pd.get_dummies(data[["sseqid", 'qseqid']].apply(tuple, axis=1)).cumsum()

this_zeros = pd.get_dummies(this)
this_zeros[:] = 0
pd.concat([cum, this_zeros[this_zeros.columns.difference(cum.columns)]], axis=1)
keep = pd.concat([cum, this_zeros[this_zeros.columns.difference(cum.columns)]], axis=1).lookup(data.index, this)

data=data[keep.astype(bool)]
```

and it takes to much memory.

Comment: Could you elaborate and maybe show "my previous solutions it took to much time and memory..." so that others don't waste time attempting to provide answers you already deem insufficient?

Comment: Yep, I added it at the end of my script thank you.

Comment: Does `merged = df.reset_index().merge(
    df,
    left_on=['cluster_name', 'qseqid', 'sseqid', 'qstart', 'qend'],
    right_on=['cluster_name', 'sseqid', 'qseqid', 'sstar', 'send']
)` blow up your machine? That's a possible way to narrow down your candidate space...

Comment: Yes it is still the same issue I get `Killed: 9` ...

Comment: Umm... does `pd.concat([df, df])` kill your machine?

Comment: I mean the code you gave me works but it does not make the job ^^

Comment: Yeah... I was just pointing that bit out to eliminate the possible candidates that you then need to evaluate - you could possibly apply that first, then see if your other approaches are suitable.

Comment: Yes, I tried but it's still not possible for my computer to do it ...